# Is it good idea to use jquery function that run each 500ms?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created some kind of lazy load for images. It works like this:

Every 500ms it check photoes which one  you see on  device and if you see it begin to load real image and this function will never run for images that loaded but if image cant load it will try again when you see this image again.

Is there any problem to use that kind of function every 500ms?

Comment: So basically you are sending request to `server` every _500ms_ to load real image.. I feel this will be a heavy load to `server` when you send request every _500ms_. Better to increase time..

Comment: My main question is why? What makes you think it will be able to load the image a second time if it failed the first?

Comment: No.I dont @Guruprasad Rao.It just send request for images that doesnt load once if error happens on loading it will try again when you reagain see it on your screen you need just scroll down and up and see again and request will send again

Comment: @Liam because maybe user load content but suddenly internet connection broke and image will not load untill user reagin see it

Comment: If the image failed to load the first time... There's a good chance it will fail the second time too. Hammering the server to try and get images to load sounds like the wrong solution.

Comment: No.It will not request suddenly.It will send request when your screen lose image and see again.@scunliffe

Comment: You should probably ask yourself why no one else does this. For me this seems like a lot of work and load for an edge case.

Comment: Actually ,facebook,twitter app use some king of thing but it is on app.And I want to do this for web.@Liam

Comment: @IbrahimHasanov simply you can check if user lose internet connection and do that once connection lost, not keep trying every 500ms

Comment: How I can check it?Also i dont check every 500ms ,I check images which user see once and if image doesnt load. It will not check it again and again,it will check it when images will be unvisible then visible for user.For example user see image but it will not loaded and user scroll down then internet connection created and user scroll up and image will send request again @mohammed-ibrahim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using this in response to the images coming into view? Rather than polling every 500ms all the images on the page to see if they're in view, perhaps it would be better to trigger the check *only when the page has scrolled* (or whatever causes images to scroll. You could still limit this to be no more frequent than once every 500ms, but it has the benefit of:

1. Not having a 500ms interval loop running all the time
2. Not checking the images in view unnecessarily

I'll assume the images come in and out of view as the user scrolls, so what you'd want to do in that instance is as follows:

1. Bind an event to `$(window).scroll`
2. Have it fire an event after a fixed period with `setTimeout` (500ms in your case).
3. Cancel that timer if the user scrolls again and start it (to prevent it firing multiple times.
4. **Listen** for the event firing and perform your image check there.

Here's an example of how the code might look:

```
var scrollIntervalTimeout;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  // Cancel the timeout and start it again
  clearTimeout(scrollIntervalTimeout);
  scrollIntervalTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $(window).trigger('scrollDidEnd');
  }, 500); // 500ms delay before firing the event
});

// Listen for the scrollDidEnd event
$(window).on('scrollDidEnd', function() {
  // Perform your image check here
});
```

Comment: My function doesnt run for load every time my function run for check user view that :is there any new image to load?if there is it will begin to load it.if this image is unloaded image it will load it once.if image reenter view it will check it again.I just want to leanr that is it good to check user view every 500 ms.What is the disadvantage of this?

Comment: ok.I tried your function but it didnt work for appended new images.I want to learn that is there any disadvantage for performance to run function that just check view of user each 500 ms?